# Sharepoint OOB Spellcheck requiring login

Tags: sharepoint

We're trying to use the built in SharePoint spell check functionality but unfortunately it seems that it doesn't allow anonymous users to access the page.  I'm calling the spell via the normal JS call:

```
<SharePoint:ScriptLink ID="ScriptLink1" Language="javascript" Name="core.js" runat="server" />
<SharePoint:ScriptLink ID="ScriptLink2" Language="javascript" Name="bform.js" runat="server" />
<SharePoint:ScriptLink ID="ScriptLink3" Language="javascript" Name="SpellCheckEntirePage.js" runat="server" />

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function SpellCheck() {
    SpellCheckEntirePage('/_vti_bin/SpellCheck.asmx', '/_layouts/SpellChecker.aspx');
}
</script>
```

Basically it seems that the /_layouts/SpellChecker.aspx page is the issue.  I made a copy of the file and moved it to the pages library and referenced it there and it fixed the issue for that page but then it was requiring login for the master page that page uses and some controls.  Short of attempting to locate and copy out each referenced page (which I'm not convinced will even work in the first place) I'm not sure what will fix the overall issue.

Am I missing something here or is it just going to not work?